# Network manager is not asking for password when connecting to new Wifi networks

Tags: wireless, network-manager

Recently my ubuntu 14.04 LTS stopped asking for password for wifi networks. This makes it impossible for me to connect to new wifi networks. And even the wifi icon from top right of the screen has disappeared. I can connect to my old wifi network whose password I mentioned earlier, but connecting to new wifi is impossible. I go to network manager and click on the wifi network I want to connect, I select "settings" to enter the password but nothing happens.Network manager is not even prompting for a password. What should I do? Someone please help me. Thanking you in advance